# How can I write a php code that display the 3 tables based on the IDs in json format?

Tags: php, mysql, json, flutter, inner-join

I have these 3 tables

```
Table student:
student_id | student_name  |
1          | Amber*        |
2          | Erwin         |

Table course:
course_id | studentid   |course_name  |
1         | 1*          |Math         |
2         | 2           |English      |
3         | 1*          |History      |

Table grade:
grade_id | courseid     | grade_a    | grade_b |
1        | 1*           | 85         | 90      |
2        | 3*           | 81         | 79      |
3        | 2            | 85         | 79      |
```

I tried:

```
("SELECT * FROM student
INNER JOIN course ON course.studentid = student.student_id
INNER JOIN grade ON grade.courseid = course.course_id
WHERE student.student_id = 1");
```

I want to achieve this...

```
Student: Amber

              GRADE A      GRADE B
Math             85          90
History          81          79
```

I also used **GROUP BY** but it won't work... https://ikns.info/api/signin-data?studentid=1

I'm working a flutter project with json http request.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Hi Atnaize no it's not working.. i'll show you the output https://ikns.info/api/signin-data?studentid=1